# Azure Application Insights does not log Redis calls

Tags: azure, redis, azure-application-insights

We just implemented Azure Application Insights service for our application. The service logs all of our remote dependencies but **Redis** calls, which we use for `Session` and .Net `OutputCache`. Redis wrapper is `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName`.

Has anyone faced the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Redis client is communicating via [RESP protocol over TCP connection (port 6379)](http://redis.io/topics/protocol), which is not supported by [Application Insights Dependency Collector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector) that we provide.
Implementing a custom dependency collection module for Redis should be possible ([please see our GH repository for examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-server-dotnet/tree/master/Src/DependencyCollector)) or you can just call [TrackDependency API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#track-dependency) manually.

Comment: Thanks but we don't own the code that connects to redis. We use it for session and cache with Microsoft  provided libraries. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/ https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-asp.net-output-cache-provider/